# django templates index of array does not work

Tags: python, django, templates, indexing

Index in templates of django is like this:
`{{somearray.i}}`
for my code this is not working!!

this is views.py

```py
def fadakpage(request):
    tours = tour.objects.order_by('tourleader')
    travelers = traveler.objects.order_by('touri')
    j=0
    for i in tours:
        j+=1
    args={'tours':tours,'travelers':travelers,'range':range(j)}
    return render(request,'zudipay/fadakpage.html',args)
```

this is `fadakpage.html / template` (it shows empty):

```html
{% for i in range %}
      {{tours.i.tourleader}}
{% endfor %}
```

but if i change `{{tours.i.tourleader}}` to `{{tours.0.tourleader}}` it works!!
I also checked I values and it was true !!

Comment: Do you require the index in your loop? If not, then Daniel Roseman's answer is all you need

Comment: yes i saw his answer but yes i need the index .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need. You can get the loop counter by using `{{ forloop.counter }}` to get the loop index starting at 1, or `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` to get the index starting at 0.

```
{% for tour in tours %}
      {{ tour.tourleader }} {{ forloop.counter }}
{% endfor %}
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

No, indeed, that does not work in a Django template. But there is no reason to do it: just loop through `tours`.

```
{% for tour in tours %}
      {{tour.tourleader}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i know that but I have summarized my code. in continue i need the index of a tour in tours!

Answer (score 0):

You change your view to this:

```py
def fadakpage(request):
    j = 0
    tours = []
    for i in tour.objects.order_by('tourleader'):
        tours.append((i, j))
        j += 1
    args = {'tours': tours, 'range': range(j)}
    return render(request, 'zudipay/fadakpage.html', args)
```

And use list of tuples in your template:

```html
{% for tour in tours %}
  {{ tour.0.tourleader }}
{% endfor %}
```

In this code in your template `{{ tour.0 }}` is `tour` object and `{{ tour.1 }}` is count.